# python3 unicode string comparsion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, equals, string-comparison

I have a string that comes from a process' output, which seems to be unicode, and I can't compare it to a 'normal' string.

Here is the code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
result = re.match(r'#title#(?P<title>.*)#artist#(?P<artist>.*)#track#(?P<track>.*)#islive#(?P<islive>.*)', out.decode("utf-8"))
if result:
    print(result.group('islive'))
    print('na')

    print(result.group('islive').lower() == 'na')
```

The output:

```
u'NA'
na
False
```

The python version is Python 3.6.5.

I need some help on how to compare these two strings.

Comment: What if you `print(repr(result.group('islive').lower())`, to find out exactly what you've got?

Comment: it prints out "u'na'"

Answer (score 0):

If comparing to `u'na'` (which should be preferred due to being faster) is not an option you can utf-8 encode your unicode string before comparing.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
result = re.match(r'#title#(?P<title>.*)#artist#(?P<artist>.*)#track#(?P<track>.*)#islive#(?P<islive>.*)', out.decode("utf-8"))
if result:
    print(result.group('islive'))
    print('na')

    print(result.group('islive').lower().encode('utf8') == 'na')
```

Comment: with .encode('utf8') it prints b"u'na'", but still not equals

Comment: Wait, is the String u'na'? what do you get when you do this? print('"{}"'.format(result.group('islive')))

Comment: "u'NA'" that's what i got

Comment: That explains it. The string is litteraly "u'NA' and not the unicode characters NA

Comment: result.group('islive').lower().encode('utf8') == "u'na'", since the string is u'na' and not na